# Find the value in a matrix with certain condition

Tags: matlab, matrix

How to find the value in a matrix with certain condition. For example,

```
a=[-3.14,2.12,-5,3,6,7];

b=find(a>0)
```

this will return the indices of matrix with that ">0" condition, which is b= 2 4 5 6.

do we have any solution for find the actual value in a matrix under that condition, such as returning b= 2.12 3 6 7 ?

Answer (score 5):

you can even skip the find part:

```
whatyouwant = a(a>0);
```

That's called logical indexing in Matlab...

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following

```
a = [-3.14,2.12,-5,3,6,7];

b = find(a>0)

c = a(b)
```

The `c` would then be the selected values based on the indices in `b.`

Hope it helps!